# ResourceCursorAdapter to work with Content Provider

Tags: android, sql, cursor, android-contentprovider

**INTRODUCTION**

I'm starting to work with SQL databases, Content Providers and Cursors. I'm working on an app which consists on this:

**DESCRIPTION**

The app starts with a ListActivity where there is a list of travels which show "**City**", "**Country**", "**Year**", and a "**Note**". If I click on the ActionBar's menu, it shows the option to `create a new travel` (it starts a new activity with few edtitext where to set the previous parameters and a button to save). If I long click on each list item, it appears a context menu with the options to `edit` (it would send to the same activity where a new travel is created) or to `delete`a travel.

**CONDITIONS**

To do this, I have to work with the `ResourceCursorAdapter`. I slightly understand how to implement the **SQLiteOpenHelper** and the `ContentProvider`, but I'm not sure on how to work with the `Cursor` to mannage the data on the activity.

**TROUBLE**

Where I'm having troubles is mannaging the data in the main activity. I'm not able to update neither delete an item from the list, and I think this is related to that I don't know how to work with the ID to indicate with element I'm working with.

**CODE**

SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class TravelsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "travels.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "travels";

    public TravelsDatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            Travels._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            Travels.CITY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Travels.COUNTRY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Travels.YEAR + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Travels.NOTE + " TEXT " +
            ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < newVersion){
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + ";");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

ContentProvider

```
public class TravelsProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.travellist";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/travels");

    private TravelsDatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    //UriMatcher
    private static final int URI_TRAVELS = 1;
    private static final int URI_TRAVEL_ITEM = 2;

   private static final UriMatcher mUriMatcher;
    static {
        mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "travels", URI_TRAVELS);
        mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "travels/#", URI_TRAVEL_ITEM);
    }


    public class Travels implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String CITY = "city";
        public static final String COUNTRY = "country";
        public static final String YEAR = "year";
        public static final String NOTE = "notes";
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mDbHelper = new TravelsDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long id = database.insert(TravelsDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Uri result = null;

        if (id >= 0){
            result = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;
        database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int match = mUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match){
            case URI_TRAVELS:
                //nada
                break;
            case URI_TRAVEL_ITEM:
                String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                count = database.update(TravelsDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, Travels._ID +
                    " = " + id + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                            selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;
        database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int match = mUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match){
            case URI_TRAVELS:
                //nada
                break;
            case URI_TRAVEL_ITEM:
                String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                count = database.delete(TravelsDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, Travels._ID +  " = " + id +
                    (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                            selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        int match = mUriMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qBuilder.setTables(TravelsDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME);

        switch (match){
            case URI_TRAVELS:
                //nada
                break;
            case URI_TRAVEL_ITEM:
                String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                qBuilder.appendWhere(Travels._ID + "=" + id);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        Cursor c = qBuilder.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        int match = mUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match){
            case URI_TRAVELS:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.travels";
            case URI_TRAVEL_ITEM:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.travels";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class TravelListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_TRAVEL = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_TRAVEL = 1;
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {Travels._ID, Travels.CITY,
    Travels.COUNTRY, Travels.YEAR, Travels.NOTE};
    private TravelsCursorAdapter mAdapter;


    final class TravelsCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
        private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public TravelsCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 0);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            holder.text1 = textView1;
            holder.text2 = textView2;
            view.setTag(holder);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            String city = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travels.CITY));
            String country = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travels.COUNTRY));
            int year = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Travels.YEAR));
            String note = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travels.NOTE));

            holder.text1.setText(city + " (" + country + ")");
            holder.text2.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.year) + " " + year);
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
    }  


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initialData();
        getTravelsAdapter();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    public void getTravelsAdapter() {
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

        mAdapter = new TravelsCursorAdapter(this, c);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


    /**
     * OptionsMenu
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_new_travel:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditTravelActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_TRAVEL);
                break;

            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
     }


    /**
     * onActivityResult
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_TRAVEL:
                    String ncity = data.getExtras().getString(Travels.CITY);
                    String ncountry = data.getExtras().getString(Travels.COUNTRY);
                    int nyear = data.getExtras().getInt(Travels.YEAR);
                    String nnote = data.getExtras().getString(Travels.NOTE);

                    insertTravel(ncity, ncountry, nyear, nnote);
                    getTravelsAdapter();
                    break;
                case REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_TRAVEL:
                    String ucity = data.getExtras().getString(Travels.CITY);
                    String ucountry = data.getExtras().getString(Travels.COUNTRY);
                    int uyear = data.getExtras().getInt(Travels.YEAR);
                    String unote = data.getExtras().getString(Travels.NOTE);

                    updateTravel(ucity, ucountry, uyear, unote);
                    getTravelsAdapter();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * onListItemClick
     */
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TravelActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Travels.CITY, );
        intent.putExtra(Travels.COUNTRY, );
        intent.putExtra(Travels.YEAR, );
        intent.putExtra(Travels.NOTE, );

        startActivity(intent);
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }


    /**
     * ContextMenu
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterContextMenuInfo menu_info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit_travel:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditTravelActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_TRAVEL);
                return true;
            case R.id.delete_travel:
                deleteTravel(menu_info.id);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    private void initialData(){
        insertTravel("Londres", "UK", 2012, "�Juegos Olimpicos!");
        insertTravel("Paris", "Francia", 2007, null);
        insertTravel("Gotham City", "EEUU", 2011, "��Batman!!");
        insertTravel("Hamburgo", "Alemania", 2009, null);
        insertTravel("Pekin", "China", 2011, null);
    }

    private void insertTravel(String city, String country, int year, String note){
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(Travels.CITY, city);
        newValues.put(Travels.COUNTRY, country);
        newValues.put(Travels.YEAR, year);
        newValues.put(Travels.NOTE, note);

        getContentResolver().insert(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, newValues);
    }

    public void updateTravel(String city, String country, int year, String note){
        ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
        updateValues.put(Travels.CITY, city);
        updateValues.put(Travels.COUNTRY, country);
        updateValues.put(Travels.YEAR, year);
        updateValues.put(Travels.NOTE, note);

        getContentResolver().update(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, updateValues, null, null);
    }

    private void deleteTravel(long id){
        getContentResolver().delete(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, Travels._ID+"="+id, null);
    }

    public ArrayList<TravelInfo> getTravelsList(){

        ArrayList<TravelInfo> travels = new ArrayList<TravelInfo>();

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, Travels.YEAR);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
            int cityIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Travels.CITY);
            int countryIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Travels.COUNTRY);
            int yearIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Travels.YEAR);
            int noteIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Travels.NOTE);

            do {
                String city = c.getString(cityIndex);
                String country = c.getString(countryIndex);
                int year = c.getInt(yearIndex);
                String note = c.getString(noteIndex);

                TravelInfo travel = new TravelInfo(city, country, year, note);
                travels.add(travel);
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }
        return travels;
    }
}
```